# Table with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: php, css, angularjs

I would like to have a table on my website.
The problem is that this table is too wide (because there is a lot of records from database ).
How can I add horizontal scrollbar? Now my table is only responsive and text is doing in this way
[image]

This is my **HTML** code:

```
<table class="hoverable bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Row1</th>
            <th>Row2</th>
            <th>Row3</th>
            <th>Row4</th>
            <th>Row5</th>
            <th>Row6</th>
            <th>Row7</th>
            <th>Row83</th>
            <th>Row9</th>
            <th>Row10</th>
            <th>Row11</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define width and overflow property.Set width >=100% and overflow-x:auto;

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the following css code into the head tag

```
table {
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
  display:    table;
  width:      100%;
  height:     100vh; /* Optional */
}
```

If this is not working, try putting the table inside a div and set the overflow-x for the div and leave the display: table for the table.